# compare multiple strings in single input in C

Tags: c, unix

I currently have a piece of code that compares 1 input to a variable...
for example, when i input "GET" it compares it to the string i have set and then opens a file. but what if i want to compare more than one string in the input? such as if someone inputs "GET ./homepage.html"

so the first string GET indicates that they want to retrieve a file, and the second string "./homepage.html" is the file they want to view?

My thoughts on this would be to build an array with a combination of GET + all the possible file combinations and then use `strcomp` to choose the right one and open the specified file..? but i'm not 100% on how i would link my input to compare to a whole array?

current code is below, very basic string compare -> opens and writes file to stdout.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[] ) {
MainStruct val;
parse_config(&val);
char userInput[100] = "success.txt";
char temp[100];

if (checkaccess() == 0)
{
    parse_config(&val);

} else {
    fprintf(stderr,"unable to load config file\n");

}

printf("Connected to Domain : %s", val.domain);

fgets(temp, 6, stdin);
temp[strcspn(temp, "\n")] = '\0';
if(strcmp(temp, "GET /") == 0 )
{
    openfile(userInput);

} else {
    printf("that was not a very valid command you gave\n");
}





}
```

EDIT: i should also mention that the second string input should also == userInput that the function `openfile` reads in. not sure how to separate out the two strings.

Comment: I would use strtok to separate the string into tokens and than process them. Alternatively, you can use getopt which is the standard for processing input parameters.

Comment: @IshayPeled could you provide a short example?

Comment: Sure, you can find an example herehttp://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_strtok.htm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of ways to approach this. The most straight forward is to read your full line of input into `temp` and then break `temp` into tokens with `strtok` or the like. The line of input would include your command (e.g. `GET`) and any other values you need to act upon. You can then make a decision if you received sufficient input (i.e. `GET` and a `filename`) to then respond as you intend.

Below is a short example that creates an array of char arrays (strings) to hold the tokens entered as `temp`. A couple of defines at the beginning limit each token to `64` chars and the maximum number of tokens to `5` (adjust as needed) It then breaks `temp` into tokens and checks whether the user entered more than 1 word. It then responds to `GET` and shows the `filename` it collected. (you can take whatever action you need). It also checks the number of tokens entered to make sure you don't try and write beyond the end of the array.

Take a look and let me know if you have questions:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAXISZ 64
#define MAXIN  5

int main (void) {

    char temp[MAXISZ] = {0};            /* temp variable    */
    char input[MAXIN][MAXISZ] = {{0}};  /* array of strings to hold input */
    size_t icnt = 0;                    /* number of input words          */
    size_t tlen = 0;                    /* length of temp read by fgets   */

    printf ("\n Enter command [filename]: ");
    if (fgets (temp, MAXISZ, stdin) == NULL) {
        printf ("error: fgets failed.\n");
        return 1;
    }

    /* get length and trim newline */
    tlen = strlen (temp);
    while (tlen > 0 && temp[tlen - 1] == '\n')
        temp[--tlen] = 0;

    /* if temp contains a space */
    if (strchr (temp, ' '))
    {
        /* break tmp into tokens and copy to input[i] */
        char *p = NULL;
        for (p = strtok (temp, " "); p != NULL; p = strtok (NULL, " "))
        {
            strcpy (input[icnt++], p);

            /* check if MAXIN reached */
            if (icnt == MAXIN)
            {
                printf ("error: MAXIN token exceeded.\n");
                break;
            }
        }

        /* if more than 1 word input, use 1st as command, next as filename */
        if (icnt > 0)
        {
            if (strcmp (input[0], "GET") == 0)
                printf ("\n  You can open file : %s\n", input[1]);
        }

    }
    else
        printf ("\n  Only a single word entered as command '%s'.\n", temp);

    printf ("\n");

    return 0;
}
```

**Output**

```
$ ./bin/fgets_split

 Enter command [filename]: GET /path/to/myfile.txt

  You can open file : /path/to/myfile.txt
```

or

```
$ ./bin/fgets_split

 Enter command [filename]: GET

  Only a single word entered as command 'GET'.
```